# CS1503 cannot convert from class A to class A - strange Xamarin Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I just started to work with Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017 few days ago. I run into some weird errors here and there. Here's the one Google search doesn't know about.

Here's the error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'myTests.Models.ThisWeeksInfo
>   [myTests.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]' to 'myTests.Models.ThisWeeksInfo [myTests,
>   Version=1.0.6358.30657, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]' myTests.Droid   C:\git-shared\myTests\myTests\ThisWeeksPage.xaml.cs 29  Active

So, to me it can't convert from same class to same class.

Here's my code :

model :

```
namespace myTests.Models
{
    /**
         * a model for This week's people   
         */
    public class ThisWeeksInfo
    {
        public Profile profile { get; private set; }
        public string messageFromePerson { get; private set; }

        public ThisWeeksInfo(Profile profile, string messageFromePerson)
        {
            this.profile = profile;
            this.messageFromePerson = messageFromePerson;
        }

    }
}
```

call :

```
using myTests.Models;


private void onItemClicked(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item == null) return;

    var thisWeeksInfo = e.Item as ThisWeeksInfo;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new ThisWeeksMessageDetailPage(thisWeeksInfo));
}
```

the responding Page :

```
using myTests.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace myTests
{
    public partial class ThisWeeksMessageDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ThisWeeksInfo info { get; private set; }
        public ThisWeeksMessageDetailPage(ThisWeeksInfo info)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.info = info;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

           nameLabel.BindingContext = info;
        }
    }
}
```

So, it basically says that it cannot convert ThisWeeksInfo's object in one class to the ThisWeeksInfo's object in another page class in .Droid (and also, .iOS) project, but doesn't say anything on the cross-platform project.

What possibly can I check? 
I already cleaned project, rebuilt it, deleted obj and bin directories wherever possible and also .suo file.

Comment: Where is the `ThisWeeksInfo` source code file? Is it only in a shared project? Do you use Shared or Portable Class Library? To me it looks like you are trying to cast a class that exists in the Android project to a class that exists in a shared library. Their name is same but if you look at the error message, you'll see their assembly is different.

Comment: @juunas yes, it's in the portable. Other classes worked from portable in Droid and iOS, but this one doesn't want to

Comment: Okay, in the Android project, can you try clicking F12 on `ThisWeeksInfo` on the `ThisWeeksInfo info` property in the page class? That should take you to the class definition. That should be the one in the PCL.

Comment: @juunas I'm sorry, but my myTests.Droid project is almost empty. The only one which contains any classes is myTests(portable). But in both classes that uses ThisWeeksInfo pressing F12 leads to the same model class

Comment: While they have the same name and namespaces they belong to different assemblies. The file/class may be shared between differing projects.

Comment: @Nkosi how can I fix it? and why other classes doesn't have the same error?

Comment: This looks like a mismatched assembly version (`Version=1.0.0.0` != `Version=1.0.6358.30657`). What does your solution look like, do you have multiple different assemblies (projects) in your solution? Is it maybe possible that you've added the version `1.0.0.0` DLL as reference in one of your projects manually (instead of adding a project reference)?

Comment: We were able to solve this same problem by making sure we were using a Shared Project rather than a standard Class Library project.